# Expand a function in Maclaurin's series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Please help me expand this function in Maclaurin's series to find an interval of convergence.

[image]

I tried to turn it into this expression:

[image]

but it doesn't give me the result. Help me please it's very important

Comment: If we change variable names, you have the right expression for $(1+t)^\alpha$. Now replace $t$ everywhere by $x^2$.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, but your method is the most efficient, I suspect. You set $\alpha=-1/3$ and replaced $x$ by $x^2$, right? And then increased each $x$-exponent by $1$?